# How many different divisors the number 504 has?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I see this question a lot [im learning to discrete math test] and always put it away.
Do you have maybe a way to solve this?
Because i dont see other way than try in the calculator like an hour..
Thank you very much.
The question is: "How many different divisors the number 504 has? Find the sum of all the divisors."

Comment: Do you mean divisors?

Comment: Here they are $$\left\{ 1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,12,14,18,21,24,28,36,42,56,63,72,84,126,168,
252,504 \right\} 
$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner My question is HOW to getto  the answer not searching in google and find it..

Comment: Where are your notes on the topic? What have you tried already to solve the problem? (even brute force works eventually)

Comment: At first i would compute the prime factors of the given numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Start with the prime factorization of 504. Let's say it's $504=p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}\cdots p_r^{a_r}$. What can you say about the number of divisors in terms of $a_i$?

Solution: This is called the divisor function, usually denoted $d(n)$. If you know the prime factorization of a number $n$, then $$d(n)=\prod_{i=1}^r(a_i+1).$$ So since $504=2^33^27^1$, we have $d(504)=(3+1)(2+1)(1+1)=4\cdot3\cdot2=24.$

As for the sum of divisors, this has a similar formula, namely $$\nu(n)=\prod_{i=1}^r \frac{p_i^{a_i+1}-1}{p_i-1}.$$ Hence $\nu(504)=\left(\frac{2^{3+1}-1}{2-1}\right)\left(\frac{3^{2+1}-1}{3-1}\right)\left(\frac{7^{1+1}-1}{7-1}\right)=15\cdot13\cdot8=1560.$

See more: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function

Comment: Gracias Andrew!! just one question i didnt get properly - if for the example asking me the divisors of the number 100, and the prime factorization is 2^2 and 5^2, so im always taking the exponent and adding it one? - (2+1)(2+1) = 9 ? 100 has 9 divisors am i right? ive got it? @andrew

Comment: That's correct!

Comment: Amazing thank you a lot!!!! you have no idea how much youve helped me.. im stuck witht it like 2 hours seriously

Comment: oh andwer one moment - if they asking me to make a list of all the 24 divisors - i need to sit with the calculator and just check what divisor 504? and knowing it will be total 24 ?

Comment: There's an easier way than just trying every number up to 504. You know the prime factorization of 504, and you know that any number that divides 504 must also have a prime factorization of a similar form.  For example, since 5 does not appear as a prime factor of 504, it cannot then appear as a prime factor of any divisor of 504.  This means you can algorithmically generate the 24 divisors of 504. Treat the prime factorization of 504 as a "pool" from which you can draw. Depending on how many of which prime factors you pull, you will get a different divisor of 504.

Comment: So, for example, if you pull no factors from the pool, you get the divisor 1. If you take them all, you get 504 itself.  Let's say you take 2 factors of 2 and 1 of 7. Then you have 4*7=28 is a divisor of 504 (which you can easily check to be correct).  So, generate all the divisors by first taking none, then taking one by one of the first prime factor, then take none of the first and one of the second, then repeat that until you take all the factors of the second, then take one of the third and none of the first or second, and so on.

Comment: So basically i need to make all the combinations for making a list of the divisors? thank you very much

Comment: @LORINECHERRY  Since $504 = 2^33^27^1$, every factor of $504$ is of the form $2^a3^b7^c$, where $a \in \{0, 1, 2, 3\}$, $b \in \{0, 1, 2\}$, and $c \in \{0, 1\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $504=2^3\cdot3^2\cdot7$. Does prime factorization help?